# Delphi 2007 corrupting .dproj files

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007

I've just started working with Delphi 2007 again, and noticed that it has then annoying tendency to add invalid references, duplicate references, and reference `.dcp` files in completely the wrong directory in `.dproj` files.  This probably wouldn't be such a problem but it breaks some IDE plugins that I like to use (cnPack for instance).

Cleaning this up manually is very annoying.  Deleting the `.dproj` file works, but loses version info, description etc.  Is there some sort of automatic way of cleaning up these project files.

EDIT: A specific example.
If I create a new project, edit the .dpr (from within Delphi) and add a new unit manually, so that the .dpr looks something like

```
program Project4;

uses
  Forms,
  Unit5 in 'Unit5.pas' {Form5},
  Unit3 In 'Unit3.pas';

{$R *.res}

begin
  Application.Initialize;
  Application.MainFormOnTaskbar := True;
  Application.CreateForm(TForm5, Form5);
  Application.Run;
end.
```

And now Save, the `<ItemGroup>` section of the .dproj looks like this

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <DelphiCompile Include="Project4.dpr">
      <MainSource>MainSource</MainSource>
    </DelphiCompile>
    <DCCReference Include="U">
      <Form>$R *.res</Form>
    </DCCReference>
    <DCCReference Include="Un">
      <Form>$R *.res</Form>
    </DCCReference>
    <DCCReference Include="Uni">
      <Form>$R *.res</Form>
    </DCCReference>
    <DCCReference Include="Unit">
      <Form>$R *.res</Form>
    </DCCReference>
    <DCCReference Include="Unit3">
      <Form>$R *.res</Form>
    </DCCReference>
    <DCCReference Include="Unit3.p">
      <Form>$R *.res</Form>
    </DCCReference>
    <DCCReference Include="Unit3.pa">
      <Form>$R *.res</Form>
    </DCCReference>
    <DCCReference Include="Unit3.pas">
      <Form>$R *.res</Form>
    </DCCReference>
    <DCCReference Include="Unit5.pas">
      <Form>Form5</Form>
    </DCCReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Where it should look like

```
  <ItemGroup>
    <DelphiCompile Include="Project4.dpr">
      <MainSource>MainSource</MainSource>
    </DelphiCompile>
    <DCCReference Include="Unit3.pas" />
    <DCCReference Include="Unit5.pas">
      <Form>Form5</Form>
    </DCCReference>
  </ItemGroup>
```

Similar problems seem to occur to the `.dproj` file when removing references from the `.dpr` or `.dpk` file.

I hope this makes the question clearer.

Comment: Revision control system

Comment: I use D2007 every single day (it's still our primary development version due to some compatibility issues), and I've never seen the .dproj break anything. (I also use cnPack and GExperts, as well as the JCL and JVCL, and have never had any of them *break* as a result of content in the .dproj.)

Comment: It seems that Alister is not as lucky

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yes it is in version control, currently I'm making changes to the `.dpr` and `.dpk` files (removing unused units)- it would be nice to not have to maintain the `.dproj` file manually.

Comment: I've used Delphi versions 7, 2010, XE2, and XE7, and have never ever had a problem with dproj files. It must be something special you're doing such as using certain add-ons (or combinations of them) (well they didn't exist in D7).

Comment: @David: Or that Alister is doing something that others are not. Without someone else having experienced the issue (or steps to reproduce it for the rest of us), it's highly unlikely anyone is going to be able to help, making it relevant that neither Jerry or me (and apparently you) haven't seen it before.

Comment: @KenWhite Well, I've never used D2007 FWIW. But your last comment is the most helpful I feel. You are asking Alister for details of how this problem arises.  Without knowing what the problem actually is, how can we suggest a solution. So, Alister, I would say that unless you actually describe the problem so that it can be recognised, there's no question here yet.

Comment: Addressing your edit: You can avoid that particular issue by never putting your manually added unit after any of the IDE maintained entries (the ones ending with `{FormX}`; the IDE expects to find those at the end of the `uses` in the .dpr` file because that file is technically the property of the IDE itself. (It's fine to add to it, but do so in the proper location, just like the IDE added the `Forms` unit.) I've also never seen that issue affect anything other than the Project Manager UI tree, although it occasionally will cause the IDE to add an extra `{$R *.res}` in the .dpr.

Comment: (continued) The extra `{$R }` entry causes a linker warning about a duplicate resource (which is of course right, because the IDE included it twice); it's a known issue with the IDE that has existed for several versions, that can be fixed by finding the first `{$ *.res}` entry at the end of one of the form lines (`{FormX} {$R *.res},`) and removing it.

Comment: @KenWhite I've been having this problem with `.dpk` files also - I've been removing components from packages, I just used this example as it is easy to reproduce.  I agree that almost everything works fine within the IDE.  The Uses cleaner in cnPack has troubles with invalid entries in the `.dproj` file and some other minor glitches.  As a solution I might have to recreate the '.dproj` file, and copy the `<ItemGroup>` section from the new one to the old one (to keep all the version and description information).

Comment: The advice @Ken gave about order of units in the .dpr file is wrong, unless D2007 is radically different from other Delphis. You can manually add them anywhere. The IDE maintains all of them. Not just the ones with `{FormX}`. Those are the forms as opposed to the plain code units.

Comment: I wonder if you've got some Unix linefeeds or some other non printing character on the dpr or dproj file.

Comment: @David: Then you've clearly never experienced the problem with an out-of-place `{$R *.res}` that causes the dupe resource error. Lucky you. I have (many times), and the ordering of the units does in fact make a difference. I'll be more polite than you, however, and not just flat out state that you're wrong just because you don't know about it.

Comment: @Ken When I add a code only unit, is it added to the dpr file? When I change the name of a code only unit, does its name change in the dpr file. Are the units with `{FormX}` the only units that the ide manages in the dpr file? I guess I got that all wrong. Sorry.

Comment: @David: I said nothing about the IDE not **touching** those files. I said that intermingling them causes **ISSUES** with the IDE occasionally. Yes, the answers to all of your questions are yes. Now please read what I wrote again and make an effort to actually understand what I wrote. I've used every version of Delphi since it was released (except for the dread Delphi 8), and I'm quite sure you're not the only one who knows something about the IDE and it's issues.

Comment: @Ken you wrote "You can avoid that particular issue by never putting your manually added unit after any of the IDE maintained entries (the ones ending with {FormX}; the IDE expects to find those at the end of the uses in the .dpr` file because that file is technically the property of the IDE itself. "

Comment: @David: Yes, and that's exactly what I meant. Where in that paragraph does it say that the IDE never touches or knows about the units you add, or that the IDE doesn't manage them as well? I said placing your own units ahead of the {form} units resolves *a single issue in the IDE*. Again, please read the words written instead of just interpreting them to find an excuse to nitpick when there's nothing to nitpick. People other than you are allowed to share their knowledge, express their thoughts, and offer their opinions; it doesn't automatically make their knowledge or thoughts **wrong**.

Comment: @Ken I read the words that you wrote and interpreted them the only way possible. What you wrote wasn't "automatically" wrong.

Comment: @David: What part of *You can avoid **that particular issue*** wasn't clear, then? And what does *The advice Ken gave about order of units in the .dpr file is wrong* mean? I'm certain I didn't misinterpret the meaning of **Ken's advice is wrong**

Comment: @Ken What you wrote about only some of the units in the dpr file being maintained by the ide was very clear.

Comment: @David: No, that is not what I said. Please read again more carefully. In fact, I said quite the opposite: *the .dpr` file because that file is technically the property of the IDE itself.* does not say *only some of the units..maintained by the ide*.

Comment: @Ken Sure you said that. I'm not going to continue this ridiculous argument. What you wrote is plain to see.

Comment: @David: First, you began it.Second, you've continued it. Third, if what I wrote is plain to see, why are you still  unable to comprehend what I said, even when I put the words repeatedly in front of you?

Comment: @Ken I'm talking about your original words. The ones where you suggested that not all units in the dpr file were maintained by the ide. Only the form units, according to that text. That's what you wrote. You can read it too. You didn't mean it that way. Feel free to clarify what you wrote. But it's not right to claim that those words mean something else.

Comment: @David: Ah, I see. You can't differentiate between *any* (what I wrote) and *only* (what you seem to think I wrote), and want to take something out of context to use to mean something different. Perhaps (as I've asked before) you should **read more carefully what I wrote**. In no case did I say that the IDE didn't do anything with units other than the ones it added (see *property of the IDE*). I'm sorry if you seem to be stuck on interpreting it that way, but that's your issue, not mine. Your inability to actually read what I wrote instead of what you want to believe I wrote isn't my problem.

Comment: @Ken You should stop digging. If all files are maintained by ide, how can you put files before the maintained files? It's nonsense. It's written in black and white. You might have meant something else. But that's what you wrote.

Comment: perhaps you meant that code only units should appear before form units.

Comment: @David: Which I also said (and apparently you missed): *never putting your manually added unit after any of the IDE maintained entries (the ones ending with {FormX}*. *Never after** has the same meaning as **before**.  You're still having difficulty reading what I actually wrote, it seems. Perhaps *you* should "stop digging".

Comment: @Ken Yes, never after is the same as before. We agree on that. If all files are maintained, how can there be some files that are maintained, and others that aren't? We agree on what before means. So let's try to agree on what is before what. You said, non-maintained before maintained.

Comment: also see: https://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/01/18/dproj-changed-or-not-changed/